# Stop looping in page using serialScroll jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, serialscroll

I am using a jQuery plugin for a website and I'm not the best at javascript.  What in this code keeps making the script loop and where can I stop it?  I am not sure where/if it is coming from this script or if I should be looking somewhere else...

```
    jQuery(function( $ ){   
    var $slideshow = $('#slideshow');
    var $homeslidernav = $('#navigation li button');
    var $prev = $('button.prev');
    var $next = $('button.next');
    $('#welcome h1').lettering();
    var intval = 7200;
    function ResetFunction() {
        TweenMax.killAll(true, false, true); 
    };
    function Slide1Function() {
        var Slide1 = new TimelineMax();         
        $('#section1').append([
            Slide1.to( $('.head_animation'), .2, {css:{display: 'block', opacity: '1'}}),
            Slide1.to( $('.head2_animation'), .2, {css:{ display: 'block', opacity: '1'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head2_animation'), 1.8, {css:{ top: '300px'}, ease:Expo.easeInOut}, -1.5),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char1'), .25, {css:{top: '-200px', right:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char2'), .25, {css:{top: '300px', right:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char3'), .25, {css:{top: '-400px', right:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char4'), .25, {css:{top: '-200px', left:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char5'), .25, {css:{top: '200px', left:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char6'), .25, {css:{top: '-200px', left:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char7'), .25, {css:{top: '200px', left:'1000px'}, ease:Elastic.easeOut}),

            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char1'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char2'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char3'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char4'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char5'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char6'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}}),
            Slide1.from( $('.head_animation .char7'), .3, {css:{color: '#4f3f35', fontFamily: 'MenschBold'}})       
        ]);
    };
    $slideshow.serialScroll({
        target:'#sections',
        items:'li.slide',
        prev: $prev,
        next: $next,
        axis:'xy',
        navigation: $homeslidernav,
        interval:intval,
        duration:0,
        force:true,
        constant:false,
        onBefore:function( e, elem, $pane, $items, pos ){
            $homeslidernav.removeClass('active');
            $homeslidernav.removeAttr("disabled"); 
            $homeslidernav.eq(pos).addClass('active');
            $homeslidernav.eq(pos).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#sections li.slide').removeClass('first'); 
            $('#sections li.slide').removeClass('current'); 
            $('#sections li.slide').eq(pos).addClass('current');
            if($('#section1.current').length > 0) {
                Slide1Function();
            }
            else {
                ResetFunction();
                $('.head_animation').css({'display': 'none', 'opacity':'0'});
                $('.head2_animation').css({'display': 'none', 'opacity':'0'});
            };
            e.preventDefault();
            if( this.blur )
                this.blur();
        },
        onAfter:function( elem ){
            if($('#section1.first').length > 0) {
                Slide1Function();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me.  Try some good olde fashioned debugging by commenting out lines and or blocks to help pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: Which jQuery plugins do you use? Please link/tag them. Also I think you actually should use some loops for parts of your code as a start.

Comment: Looks like he's using [this SerialScroll plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html). But without the option `cycle: true` it shouldn't loop.

Comment: Any chance you can give us a link to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the doc that @Barmar posted, that the `serialScroll` has start and stop properties. Without seeing the rest of your code, including how your implementing, it's hard to say. But I'm guessing that the `force: true` is forcing it to start, but you are not calling `stop.serialScroll` anywhere

```
start.serialScroll (Re)starts autoscrolling
stop.serialScroll Stops the autoscrolling
```

Comment: It looks to be the cycle and i just killed it.  Thanks so much!